# How should I find Splitting Field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

How should I find Splitting Field of $x^3-2$ over  $\mathbb Q$.

**My try **:

$x^3-2=(x-2^\frac{1}{3})(x^2+2^\frac{1}{3}x+2^\frac{2}{3})$

On solving I am getting the roots as $2^\frac{1}{3},\dfrac{2^\frac{1}{3}[-1+\sqrt 3 i]}{2},\dfrac{2^\frac{1}{3}[-1-\sqrt 3 i]}{2},$

But I dont know the answer is given that roots are $2^\frac{1}{3},2^\frac{1}{3}\omega ,2^\frac{1}{3}\omega ^2$ where $\omega $ is cube root of unity

Comment: $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt{3})/2$ *is* a cube root of unity and $(-1-i\sqrt{3})/2=\bar{\omega}=\omega^2$.

Comment: thanks for the answer @egreg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots you find are correct; just observe that
$$
2^{1/3}\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}=2^{1/3}\omega
$$
and that $\omega$ is indeed a cube root of unity.

You can also proceed by steps. It's clear that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ must belong to the splitting field, so we can start adding it. Now, in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, we can factor the polynomial as
$$
(x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x^2+\sqrt[3]{2}\,x+\sqrt[3]{4})
$$
If $\alpha$ is a root of the second factor, it must belong to the splitting field $F$, but then also $\omega=\alpha/\sqrt[3]{2}\in F$. The other root is $\sqrt[3]{4}/\alpha$.

From
$$
\alpha^2+\sqrt[3]{2}\,\alpha+\sqrt[3]{4}=0
$$
we get
$$
\omega^2+\omega+1=0
$$
so $\omega$ is a (non real) root of $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, hence a cubic root of unity. The other non real root is its conjugate $\bar{\omega}=\omega^{-1}=\omega^2$.

Thus
$$
F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\alpha,\sqrt[3]{4}/\alpha)=
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}\,\omega,\sqrt[3]{2}/\omega)=
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}\,\omega,\sqrt[3]{2}\,\omega^2)=
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)
$$
(the last equality can be easily proved by double inclusion).

Answer (score 1):

Splitting field will be $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},\omega)$ where w is cube roots of unity.

where $\omega =\dfrac{-1+\sqrt 3 i}{2}~\&~\omega ^2=\dfrac{-1-\sqrt 3 i}{2},$