# Working out the structure of a finitely generated field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, finitely-generated

If I want to work out write the structure of the elements in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega,2^{1/3})$, where $\omega$ is the 3rd root of unity - what is the easiest way to do so?

Since $\omega$ and $2^{1/3}$ are algebraic does that mean $\mathbb{Q}(\omega,2^{1/3})=\mathbb{Q}[\omega,2^{1/3}]$ which means we can forget about the inverses of elements as they automatically be invertible - i.e. just focus on creating the smallest ring containing $\mathbb{Q},w$ and $2^{1/3}$ and we already get a field.

Is $\mathbb{Q}[\omega,2^{1/3}]$ easy to work out? For example as we know $\omega$ and $2^{1/3}$ can both range from powers of $0$ to $2$ before they belong to $\mathbb{Q}$ again so does this mean:

Let z=2^{1/3}

$\mathbb{Q}(\omega,2^{1/3})=\mathbb{Q}[\omega,2^{1/3}]=\{a +b{\omega} +c{\omega}^2 + dz + ez^2 + f{\omega}z + g{\omega}z^2 + h{\omega}^2z + l{\omega}^2z^2 :a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,l \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Is there easier ways of working out field structure?

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible answers to the question  "Is there easier ways of working out field structure?"

1. Use the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem). We obtain, for example,
   $$
   \Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3},\omega)=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3}+\omega),
   $$
   and this is easier to write down.

Reference: [How to compute a primitive element for the splitting field of $x^3-2 \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158363/how-to-compute-a-primitive-element-for-the-splitting-field-of-x3-2-in-bbbq)

2. Describe it as the splitting field of $x^3-2$.

Reference: 
[How should I find Splitting Field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326078/how-should-i-find-splitting-field-of-x3-2-over-mathbb-q)

Comment: Was my reasoning correct?

Comment: No, the basis must have $6$ elements, since the degree over $\Bbb Q$ is $6$. In fact, its Galois group is $S_3$ and has $6$ elements, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/galois-group-of-x3-2-over-mathbb-q?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: How does knowing there is a primitive element help us write the structure?

Comment: I’ve no idea how he worked out a basis for that group. Surely $\omega ^2 $ must be a basis vector.

Comment: If we have a primitive element, say $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, then it is easy to write a basis, i.e., just $1,\sqrt{2}$ here, or $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ with basis $(1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}^2)$.

Comment: Ok thanks. How many powers would I know to put $2^{1/3} + \omega$ to?

Comment: Since $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=(S_3:1)=6$, the basis is $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots ,\alpha^5\}$, with $\alpha=2^{1/3}+\omega$.

Comment: Not sure about the $S_3$ part but the rest makes sense.

Comment: The degree of the Galois extension is the order of the Galois group, which is $S_3$ here. You know that $S_3$ has $6$ elements.